# getting wrong slug when trying to return to last page

Tags: django, django-models

Trying to create a function to return to last page, but slug is wrong and i cannot seem to get the correct slug.

### models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=True, blank=True)
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    task_completed  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description     = models.TextField(default="Task description")
    date            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date        = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('task_detail', kwargs={
            'slug':self.slug
        })

    @property
    def num_checklists(self):
        return self.checklist.count()

    @property
    def num_checklist_completed(self):
        return self.checklist.filter(check_completed = True).count()

class Project(models.Model):
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=CASCADE)

    title           = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=True, blank=True)
    developers      = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='projects')
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    description     = models.TextField(default="Project description")
    date            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_date      = models.DateTimeField()
    due_date        = models.DateTimeField()

    tasks           = models.ManyToManyField(Task, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('project_detail', kwargs={
            'slug':self.slug
        })

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def num_task(self):
        return self.tasks.count()

    @property
    def num_task_completed(self):
        return self.tasks.filter(task_completed = True).count()

    @property
    def list_developers(self):
        return self.developers.objects.all()

    @property
    def is_manager(self):
        return self.project_manager

class Team(models.Model):
    team_admin      = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=CASCADE)

    team_name       = models.CharField(max_length=55, unique=True, blank=True)
    members         = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='teams')
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    description     = models.TextField(default='Team description')
    date            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    projects        = models.ManyToManyField(Project, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.team_name)
        super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('projects', kwargs={
            'slug':self.slug
        })

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

    @property
    def list_members(self):
        return self.members.objects.all()

    @property
    def is_team_admin(self):
        return self.team_admin


class Checklist(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    date            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date        = models.DateTimeField()
    check_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    tasks           = models.ForeignKey(Task, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Checklist, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def return_url(self):
        return reverse('project_detail', kwargs={
            'slug':self.slug
        })

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def last_comment(self):
        return self.notes.latest("date")
```

### views.py

```
def teams(request):
    '''
    Display all teams
    '''
    teams   = Team.objects.all()

    context = {
        'teams': teams,
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/teams.html', context)

def projects(request, slug):
    '''
    Display all projects to given team
    '''
    team        = get_object_or_404(Team, slug=slug)
    projects    = Project.objects.filter(teams=team)

    try:
        last_project = Project.objects.latest('date')
    except:
        last_project = []

    context = {
        'projects': projects,
        'team': team,
        'last_project': last_project,
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context)

def project_detail(request, slug):
    '''
    Detailed view of given project
    '''
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug)
    tasks   = Task.objects.filter(task_completed=False, project=project)

    context = {
        'tasks': tasks,
        'project': project,
        'title': tasks
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/tasks.html', context)

def task_detail(request, slug):
    '''
    Detailed view of all tasks on given project
    '''
    checklist   = get_object_or_404(Checklist, slug=slug)

    context = {
        'checklist': checklist,
        'title': checklist,
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/checklist.html', context)
```

In the function "return_url" in checklist i am trying to get back to task that "own" the checklist. However i only able to get self.slug, the slug for the checklist, not the task, therefor i end up getting wrong redirected. It say; projects/task/slug-for-checklist

It should be projects/task/slug-for-task

### Update

When updating models, i end up not having any relation between task and checklist, but checklist knows of task, how do i make sure task knows of checklist?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is. Can you rewrite it, and perhaps share the view that is causing the problem?

Comment: Have updated the question and views, please see if it make sense for you now, sorry for the bad formated question, but it was difficult to describe for my part

Comment: but according to your modeling, a `Checklist` can belong to *zero, one or **more*** `Task`s, hence it makes not much sense to redirect to a task.

Comment: Well a checklist belongs to a task, and a task belongs to a project, how would you have done that?

Comment: but you use a `ManyToManyField` for that? If a `Checklist` belongs to *exactly* one task, you should define a `ForeignKey` from `Checklist` to `Task`.

Comment: but  a project can have many tasks.. so atleast there i need to be manytomany fields? But you want me to change the task class and make checklist a foreignkey there?

Comment: if a `Project` can have many `Task`s you define a `ManyToManyField` between a `Project` and `Task`, or a `ForeignKey` from the `Task` to the `Project` if a `Task` can belong to *exactly* one `Project`. But regardless, if a `Checklist` belongs to *one* task, you model this with a `ForeignKey`, regardless the other model relations like `Task` and `Project`.

Comment: Can you please share your template  project detail for me to have  look at it ?

Comment: updated models, but now i have a problem getting all the checklists listed in the tasks, since the checklist have foreignkey to the tasks, but the tasks does not know about the checklists

Comment: Then I have no relation between task and checklist, only checklist through task. How do i solve it so both know of eachother?